# Prove the set of all limit points of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is my proof. Is it correct?

(Here our sets are in a metric space).

Let $E$ be a set and $E'$ be the set of all limit points of $E$. Take $p\in E'$. Then every neighborhood of $P$ contains a point $q\neq p$ s.t. $q\in E$.
Take a neighborhood $N_r(p)$ for some $r>0$. This by definition is open. Clearly then all points $q\in N_k(p)$ for $0<k<r$ are in $E'$. So all such $q$ are limit points of $E$. But this was for an arbitrary neighborhood $N_r(p)$ of $p$. So then every neighborhood $N_r(p)$ of $p$ contains a neighborhood $N_k(p)\subset E'$. As this is true for any arbitrary $p\in E'$, we have every $p$ is a limit point of $E'$, and so $E'$ is closed.

/proof

Comment: You either show that the complement of $E'$ is open or that every point in the closure of $E'$ is also a limit point. Neither approach is evident in your ideas.

Comment: I have been struggling with proofs of this sort, i.e when we are  proving properties of the sets of interior points or the sets of limit points (as in this problem). Could you give an example of how to begin the correct proof (with the first idea)?

Comment: Take a line segment in $\Bbb R^2$ as $E=E'$. Then no point is an inner point as you assume with $N_k(p)\subset E'$.

Comment: I would start with your given definition of a closed set. I strongly assume that it is as the complement of an open set. Thus you have to show that each point of the complement of $E'$ is an inner point of the complement. This can be readily done by the negation of the limit point property.

Comment: Ok. This is precisely the point of my confusion then. By negating the limit point property, how do we conclude that we have an interior point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clearly then all points $q\in N_k(p)$ for $0<k<r$ are in $E'$

This is wrong. All you know about $p$ is that it has points of $E$ arbitrarily close to it. Each $N_k(p)$ will contain a point of $E$, but it doesn't have to contain "many" of them or to be filled with them completely. Points of $N_k(p)$ other than $p$ may well *not* have a sequence of $E$-points converging on them. Perhaps the only presence of $E$ inside a small neighborhood around $p$ is just a sequence of points converging on $p$, but not on any other point there.

OK. General advice. Try to think geometrically, with pictures. Especially with metric spaces, you should always imagine little open balls of radius $\epsilon$ or whatever around some point. "Open set" means every point comes with a little ball around it that's entirely in the set, too. So you should always imagine that ball and put it to use. "Closed set" means every point NOT in it comes with a little ball around it that's also DISJOINT from the set. Or alternatively "closed set" means that *every point arbitrarily close to us must be part of us*.

Try to see if you understand why what's being claimed is true geometrically. $E'$ is the set of limit points, and we want it to be closed. Means that we ought to be able to prove: if $x \notin E'$, there's a little ball around $x$ that's also entirely not in $E'$, i.e. contains no limit points of $E$. How do we find the little ball? Clearly we need to understand exactly what it means to **not** be a limit point of $E$.

$x$ is a limit point of $E$ if any ball around $x$ contains a point from $E$ (apart from $x$ itself - I won't bother to repeat this condition every time).

Now negate:

$x$ is **not** a limit point if there's **some** ball around $x$ that does **not** contain a point from $E$.

OK, so now that we understand that, we know that any $x \notin E'$ already comes with a handy open ball $B_\epsilon(x)  $ around it that is $E$-free. That's what "not being a limit point" means! But what we need is at least on the face of it a little more: we need a ball around $x$ that is $E'$-free, meaning every $y$ in that ball has *its own* ball around it that is $E$-free.

Can it be the same ball?

If you don't see this, draw an $x$, a small (open!) disc around it that is completely $E$-free (apart from $x$ itself, possibly), see if you can prove (**by drawing**) that everything in the disc is $\notin E'$.

After you figure out what the *picture* looks like, translate to formalism.

Comment: Ok; here's my revised proof. (I am short on time so I will not be fancy). Take $p\in E'^c$. It is not a limit point so $\exists N_r(p)$ st no pts are in $E$. Take $y\in N_r(p)$. Let $z=min(d(y,p),r-d(y,p))$. Then $N_z(y)\subset N_r(p)$. Then $y$ is not a lim pt of E, as $N_z(y)$ contains no pts of E. But since $y\in N_r(p)$ and $y\in E'^c$ then $p$ is interior pt of $E'^c$. Since this is for any $p$, $E'^c$ must be open, hence $E'$ is closed.

Comment: good! Only one minor flaw: from $N_z(y) \subset N_r(p)$ doesn't immediately follow that $y$ is not a limit point of $E$, because $p$ itself might be in $E$ and it is in $N_r(p)$. $p$ is the only point in $N_r(p)$ that might be in $E$. But your choice of $z$ actually ensures that $p$ itself stays outside $N_z(y)$, so actually all is good, but you want to mention this.